# Get distance information from google api and parse it in android app

Tags: android, json, google-maps, google-api, httpurlconnection

Hey i want to take the distance between to points from the google api and show it on the android app, i tried some code but it doesn't work, it won't take any string from the page:

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=New york&destination=Orlando&sensor=false&units=metric](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=New%20york&destination=Orlando&sensor=false&units=metric)

i want to get eventually only the value distance on meters from this page, so far i tried reading the page like this but it didn't worked(its running on a background task):

```
        json_url = http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=New york&destination=Orlando&sensor=false&units=metric
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((JSON_STRING_Distance = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(JSON_STRING_Distance + "\n");

            }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();


            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      //  checkForDistance = false;
    }
    return  "";
}
```

the Log says FileNotFoundException on the web page.
How can i read the page and get only the distance data i need from it?

Comment: did u see this   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/

Comment: have you got an API key?

Comment: @orisgoofo i think FileNotFoundException not occurred in this code show me full log and  (JSON_STRING_Distance = bufferedReader.readLine()) is correct ?

Comment: @RajeshRajendiran , I cant put here the entire log but here is some of the lines i was talking about: E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7fbeea1d3a30
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=New york&destination=Orlando&sensor=false&units=metric
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:238)

Comment: @orisgoofo first check response code for connection int responseCode = con.getResponseCode(); before use stream operations